# Jquery is return undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with `EF6`. On Ajax call to search, `each()` method returns `undefined` though the`length` of each array is correct.

```js
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "something",
   contentType: "html",
   success: function (result) {
     //Receive the filtering data from controller and show it for user
     SetData.append('<p>' + result.length+'</p>') //It's working correctly
     $.each(result, function (index, value) {
       var Data = "<p>" + value.supervisorName + "</p>"; // return undefined 
       console.log(value.supervisorName) //also return undefined
       SetData.append(Data);
     });
   }
});
```

`controller` method

```
public JsonResult GetSearchingData(string SearchBy, string SearchValue)
     {
        Entities5 db = new Entities5();
        List<Supervisors> StuList = new List<Supervisors>();
        StuList = db.Supervisors.Where(x => x.supervisorName.StartsWith(SearchValue) || SearchValue == null).ToList();
        var subCategoryToReturn = StuList.Select(S => new { Name = S.supervisorName });
        return Json(subCategoryToReturn, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

     }
```

Comment: Because your sending back a collection of objects with a property name `Name`, not `supervisorName` (and not related, but remove the pointless `contentType: "html",`)

Comment: yes It's working after change Name to supervisorName

Answer (score 0):

It's working after I change Name to supervisorName

```
var subCategoryToReturn = StuList.Select(S => new { supervisorName = S.supervisorName });
```